# Exit a specfic container if another container exited succesfully

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

i am running a pipeline locally with docker. Is there an easy way to stop broker and zookeeper after the consumer pulled all messages from the broker/jupyter-spark finished its job? I searched for options to solve that within docker-compose but did not found any. Any ideas on an easy way to solve this "problem"?

```
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "nc", "-z", "localhost", "2181"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 5



  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:latest
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-z", "localhost", "9092"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  producer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./DockerfileProducer
    volumes:
      - ./producer.py:/app/producer.py
      - ./data_cleaned_1000.csv:/app/data_cleaned_1000.csv
    command: python /app/producer.py
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: false


  consumer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./DockerfileConsumer
    volumes:
      - ./consumer.py:/app/consumer.py
    command: python /app/consumer.py
    depends_on:
      producer:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
        restart: false

  jupyter-pyspark-notebook:
    build:
      context: .  
      dockerfile: ./DockerfileSpark  
    hostname: jupyter-pyspark-notebook
    container_name: jupyter-pyspark-notebook
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    #restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./Spark.py:/app/Spark.py
    command: python /app/Spark.py
    depends_on:
      consumer:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
        restart: false
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each container in the Compose network is isolated from one another, so no. The closest option you'd get is to mount the `docker.sock` file into your Python containers, then use library like `docker-py` to inform the Docker daemon to stop your containers.

However, Kafka and Zookeeper are intended to be long-running servers, and should not be killed like this from consumer clients.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But there could be the situation, that a pipeline (batch) will only be executed once in every two month. In such cases it would make sense, that we close them until we need them again? Or do I have a misunderstanding here?

Comment: Kafka should be running on remote servers, such as Amazon MSK or Azure EventHubs... Not very often would it just be "your Spark job" that consumes from there, therefore, there is no Kafka client library that can "stop a broker". If you want to "stop a Docker container on your host", then you must use a Docker API to do that, as answered. Also, Kafka does not maintain data for more than 7 days, by default. If you want to just batch data very infrequently (months apart), then Kafka is not the correct tool for that, compared to a database, or filesystem.